# Have we observed sufficient extra-solar planetary systems to establish a planetary distribution pattern?

Tags: experimental-physics, astronomy, planets, exoplanets

From [Kepler And Extra-Solar Planetary Observations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_(spacecraft))

> As of January 2015, Kepler and its follow-up observations had found 1,013 confirmed exoplanets in about 440 stellar systems, along with a further 3,199 unconfirmed planet candidates.

Regarding the above observations, and the data gained from any similar programs,
do we currently have an idea of the distribution of planets, in terms of mass and distance from their sun's?  In particular, for stars similar in mass to our Sun, are there hints that a similar pattern to our own solar system distribution of planets exists?

I appreciate that two factors that need to be taken into account before producing a model of a "typical" stellar planetary system are the mass of the star and the fact that our data to date is biased, as far as I know, in favour of large, Jupiter scale planets.

My apologies if the answer is: ask again in 10 years when we have more data and improved observational techniques and instrumentation.

Comment: It is still the case that light planets and more distant planets are relatively hard to find. The sample is biased toward heavy, close planets. That doesn't automatically mean the problem is intractable, but it does make it harder.

Comment: Just a reminder from your Friendly Neighborhood Bayesian Statistician: the calculation and the confidence interval of the distribution depends only on the sample size and the moments (variance, mean, etc), and **not** on the total population size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is no: for now there is a high correlation between the properties of planets (size, distance to their star) and their probability to be detected, which totally bias the observed distribution.

Comment: I'ld have liked journalists and blog writers asked what you asked before writing km of silly "conclusions" ;-)